# Programming PascalABC. Why is "output" without any text?

Tags: pascal

Even just in the middle of the program I inserted "write (OutPut, '2');" and even at the very end it is, but the "output" file is still created empty.

```
program HelloFromRussia;
 var 
  s, y, h, n, x: Integer;
  InPut, OutPut: Text;
begin
 assign(InPut,'c:\input.txt'); 
 assign(OutPut,'c:\output.txt');
 reset(InPut); 
 rewrite(OutPut);
 read(InPut, y);
 write(OutPut, '1');
 for var i:=1 to y do 
  begin
  read(InPut, s);
  if s mod 2 = 0 then write(OutPut, s, ' ');
 end;
writeln(OutPut);
reset(InPut); 
read(InPut, y);
for var i:=1 to y do 
  begin
  read(InPut, s);
  if s mod 2 <> 0 then writeln(OutPut);
  write(OutPut, s, ' ');
 end;
 for h:=1 to y do begin
  if s mod 2=0 then
   n:=n+1;
  if s mod 2<>0 then
   x:=x+1;
 end;
 if (n>x) then writeln(OutPut, 'YES')
 else writeln(OutPut, 'NO');
 write(OutPut, '2');
 close(InPut);
 close(OutPut);
end.
```

Comment: Which pascal implementation are you using, FPC or something else?

Comment: idk. PascalABC --> save --> Compilate --> open  .exe with admin roots

Comment: Can you please simplify the code a bit to show a minimal example where the problem appears?

Comment: I’ve done. The problem was with Windows. Now I’m programming on my Mac with Bootcamp. 
Windows is a... ok good night.